# Why can't I use NEWSEQUENTIALID() as the default value for my column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, ssms, default-value

I'm trying to create a  table in Management Studio and after reading about the new (from SQL 2005 on) [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) function, thought I'd give it a go.

This is what I'm doing:

[image]

But it's not letting me. The error message I get is:

```
'FormTemplate (Forms)' table - Error validating the default for column 'FormTemplateId'.
```

Am I missing a trick here? I'm definitely running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work around this bug in SQL Server Management Studio just by **ignoring** the first and second warning. Changes will be saved.

Answer (score 19):

Use `CREATE TABLE`, not the GUI.

This is a bug in SSMS, already [reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124872/table-designer-does-not-support-newsequentialid-true-for-sql-2005-and-vs-2005) as well as [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/472092/newsequentialid-bug-in-management-studio#tabs) on Connect.

Comment: @5arx: poke around the 5 year old critical bugs for MySQL. MS are quite sharp in comparison

Comment: I hardly think thats a fair comparison - up until '08 mySQL was a piddling open source affair whereas SQL Server is ubiquitious - also five years ago MS were bigger than Apple is now, with all that corporate might, surely they could have fixed the holes in all that time?

Comment: @5arx Well, when you consider the number of products Microsoft supports and the new features they add with every release, I think it's understandable that an easily avoidable bug in the GUI should linger for years. It still looks bad to us as customers but as a developer I can understand.

Comment: @Nick as I developer I can't help thinking it can't be that difficult to implement this fix.

Comment: @5arx: as a developer, use raw SQL like most folk do. This is why I've never seen this bug

Comment: I'm a developer who uses databases, not a database developer. I haven't seen anyone use raw SQL to create tables since the late 90s. My point is if you're releasing a GUI, make sure it works. That's all.

Comment: @5arx - I'm with you and I bet Microsoft's developers would be too. Unfortunately, the developers don't get to prioritize their work.

Comment: @5arx - Regarding creating tables in raw SQL, it's much faster and easier when you are familiar with the syntax and need to pack in `CHECK` constraints, FK constraints, defaults, and so forth all at once into your `CREATE` statement.

Comment: @Nick - I don't doubt it at all. But I'm not a super db user and I have (mostly bad) memories of doing everything on the commandline (OSQL) back in my Oracle (pre-TOAD) days. This is why I prefer to use the GUI  :-o

Comment: The UI doesn't exactly get a lot of priority when it comes to killing bugs.  The core engine does, which it should.  The UI team doesn't exactly have a whole lot of guys on it so they get to what they can as dictated by management (if it isn't Azure at the moment it isn't getting fixed). :(

Comment: Thinking about it (and going totally off topic) its not much of a GUI really is it? Non-dba types like me still have to run scripts to do maintenance and administration jobs for example. That can really suck.

Comment: Ifyou are using teh GUI you are doing thisngs incorrectly. Changes should be done thorugh scripts and in source control never through the GUI.

Comment: To those saying you shouldn't use the GUI, it's complete nonsense.  You can source control your database perfectly well and still use the GUI for initial creation of objects.